# Zendesk Maxwell crashing/going down

Tags: mariadb, cdc, maxwell

We have maxwell running on docker in our production and it is configured to listen to changes on MariadDb tables and push them to a kafka topic. Our MariadDb has some 10-12 tables and we have configured maxwell to listen to only 4 tables and all these 4 tables are heavily used (number of writes is too high).

Recently we have seen that our Maxwell is going down, following are the few error logs we found when maxwell is going down

```
Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.037 06:10:40,037 ERROR MysqlParserListener - (parse SET STATEMENT max_statement_time = 60 FOR flush table)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.040 06:10:40,040 ERROR SchemaChange - Error parsing SQL: 'SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR flush table'

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047 06:10:40,045 ERROR AbstractSchemaStore - Error on bin log position Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3209], lastHeartbeat=1666898518069]
```

As the last error log says **Error on bin log position Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3209]**, so to verify whether bin log file with name `mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3209` exists or not we ran `SHOW binary logs;` and we found that file in list outputted by above command

Please help me in understanding what is going wrong here and help in solving the issue

**Environment Details**

1. OS: Centos
2. Platform - AWS instance(T4g Medium)
3. CPU - 2 CPU
4. RAM - 4GB

**Maxwell Version - v1.37.7**

**Note**: We are not handling DDL & our log retention is 3 days

Detailed logs that was logged when Maxwell was going down, sorry for posting huge logs :)

```
Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.084 06:10:39,082 INFO  ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.146 06:10:39,146 INFO  AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : aaa7af6d4a11b29d

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.146 06:10:39,146 INFO  AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 1.0.0

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.188 06:10:39,187 INFO  Maxwell - Maxwell v1.37.7 is booting (MaxwellKafkaProducer), starting at Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3136], lastHeartbeat=1666898518069]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.377 06:10:39,377 INFO  MysqlSavedSchema - Restoring schema id 22 (last modified at Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.046940:91534], lastHeartbeat=1666103424529])

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.502 06:10:39,502 INFO  MysqlSavedSchema - Restoring schema id 1 (last modified at Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.040524:418929], lastHeartbeat=0])

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.555 06:10:39,555 INFO  MysqlSavedSchema - beginning to play deltas...

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.576 06:10:39,576 INFO  MysqlSavedSchema - played 21 deltas in 15ms

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.601 06:10:39,601 INFO  BinlogConnectorReplicator - Setting initial binlog pos to: mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3136

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.605 06:10:39,605 INFO  MaxwellHTTPServer - Maxwell http server starting

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.607 06:10:39,607 INFO  MaxwellHTTPServer - Maxwell http server started on port 8080

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.649 06:10:39,649 INFO  BinlogConnectorReplicator - Binlog connected.

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.649 06:10:39,646 INFO  BinaryLogClient - Connected to mariadb-nlp.app.engati.local:3306 at mysql-bin-changelog.049610/3136 (sid:6379, cid:1560183)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.669 06:10:39,669 INFO  log - Logging initialized @2288ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:39.902 06:10:39,902 INFO  Server - jetty-9.4.41.v20210516; built: 2021-05-16T23:56:28.993Z; git: 98607f93c7833e7dc59489b13f3cb0a114fb9f4c; jvm 11.0.15+10

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.037 06:10:40,037 ERROR MysqlParserListener - (parse SET STATEMENT max_statement_time = 60 FOR flush table)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.040 06:10:40,040 ERROR SchemaChange - Error parsing SQL: 'SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR flush table'

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.main(Maxwell.java:336)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.start(Maxwell.java:227)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.startInner(Maxwell.java:301)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.util.RunLoopProcess.runLoop(RunLoopProcess.java:34)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.work(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:228)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getRow(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:723)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:400)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:378)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.MysqlSchemaStore.processSQL(MysqlSchemaStore.java:102)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.AbstractSchemaStore.resolveSQL(AbstractSchemaStore.java:49)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parse(SchemaChange.java:108)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parseSQL(SchemaChange.java:94)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:17)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MysqlParserListener.visitErrorNode(MysqlParserListener.java:93)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047 com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MaxwellSQLSyntaxError: SET

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047 06:10:40,045 ERROR AbstractSchemaStore - Error on bin log position Position[BinlogPosition[mysql-bin-changelog.049610:3209], lastHeartbeat=1666898518069]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.047 06:10:40,044 INFO  ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5628733f{/,null,AVAILABLE}

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.075 06:10:40,074 INFO  Server - Started @2700ms

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.075 06:10:40,074 INFO  AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@7152d3c1{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.129 06:10:40,129 INFO  BinlogConnectorReplicator - Binlog disconnected.

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.149 06:10:40,149 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping 5 tasks

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parseSQL(SchemaChange.java:94) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.8-1.jar:4.8-1]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:17) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.8-1.jar:4.8-1]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MysqlParserListener.visitErrorNode(MysqlParserListener.java:93) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187 com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MaxwellSQLSyntaxError: SET

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187 06:10:40,152 ERROR TaskManager - cause: 

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.main(Maxwell.java:336) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.start(Maxwell.java:227) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.startInner(Maxwell.java:301) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.util.RunLoopProcess.runLoop(RunLoopProcess.java:34) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.work(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:228) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getRow(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:723) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:400) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:378) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.MysqlSchemaStore.processSQL(MysqlSchemaStore.java:102) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.AbstractSchemaStore.resolveSQL(AbstractSchemaStore.java:49) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.187     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parse(SchemaChange.java:108) ~[maxwell-1.37.7.jar:1.37.7]

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.189 06:10:40,189 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.PositionStoreThread@51b3ee1b

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.191 06:10:40,189 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.producer.MaxwellKafkaProducerWorker@5ec6ffb6

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.192 06:10:40,192 INFO  KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201 06:10:40,201 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.monitoring.MaxwellHTTPServerWorker@1490968e

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.main(Maxwell.java:336)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.start(Maxwell.java:227)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.startInner(Maxwell.java:301)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.util.RunLoopProcess.runLoop(RunLoopProcess.java:34)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.work(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:228)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getRow(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:723)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:400)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.processQueryEvent(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:378)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.MysqlSchemaStore.processSQL(MysqlSchemaStore.java:102)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.AbstractSchemaStore.resolveSQL(AbstractSchemaStore.java:49)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parse(SchemaChange.java:108)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.SchemaChange.parseSQL(SchemaChange.java:94)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:17)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201     at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MysqlParserListener.visitErrorNode(MysqlParserListener.java:93)

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201 com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.ddl.MaxwellSQLSyntaxError: SET

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201 06:10:40,199 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator@5a1d68e0

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.201 06:10:40,198 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.bootstrap.BootstrapController@3857c48d

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.220 06:10:40,219 INFO  AbstractConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@7152d3c1{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}

Oct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:40.223 06:10:40,223 INFO  ContextHandler - Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5628733f{/,null,STOPPED}

ct 28, 2022 @ 06:10:41.637  06:10:41,636 INFO  TaskManager - Stopped all tasks
```

Comment: Can you check which event is at position 3209 (`mysqlbinlog /path_of_datadir/mysql-bin-changelog.049610 | more`) ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter 
`SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR flush table` this is the event. And also from logs we can see that maxwell is unable to parse above statement and throwing some errors.

Comment: Good to see [your bug report against Maxwell](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell/issues/1931).

Answer (score 0):

The java backtrace shows this is an error in Maxwell. This [was reported as issue 1931](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell/issues/1931).

The issue is that Maxwell in the v1.37.7 doesn't parse `SET STATEMENT ... FOR` against a blacklist of SQL like `FLUSH` that its meant to take no action on.

Due to a very responsive upstream, this is is now fixed in v1.39.2.

Comment: It is answered https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell/issues/1931 , simple solution is to blacklist the `SET STATEMENT...` which was causing the issue